# Need a way to get rid of group by element

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Good morning,

I've got such query:

```
SELECT
CDV.ClientNameShort as [Nazwa Wierzyciela]
,CASE
 WHEN CDV.ClientProductId = 1006 then 'Kontynuacje bieżące'
 WHEN CDV.ClientProductId in (4,1005,1048,1049) then 'Raty bieżące i Automatyzmy bieżące'
 WHEN CDV.ClientProductId = 1010 then 'Kontynuacje poagencyjne'
 WHEN CDV.ClientProductId in (1008,1007,1050) then 'Raty poagencyjne i Automatyzmy poagencyjne'
 ELSE CDV.ProductName
 END as [Kategorie sprawy]
,CASE
 WHEN CDV.ClientProductId in (4,1005,1006,1048,1049) then 81
 WHEN CDV.ClientProductId in (1010,1008,1007,1050) then 210
 ELSE 0
 END as [DPD]
,count(CDV.CaseDetailsId) as [Ilość zleceń]
,convert(date,CDV.DateImported) as [Początek obsługi]
,convert(date,CDV.EndServiceDate) as [Koniec obsługi]
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital) as [Kapitał przekazany]
,sum(CDV.PaymentValue) as [Suma wpłat]
,sum(case when CDV.CaseStatus = 'Wycofana' then CDV.CurrentCapital else 0 end) as [Wartość wycofań]
,(sum(CDV.PaymentValue))/(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital) - sum(case when CDV.CaseStatus = 'Wycofana' then CDV.CurrentCapital else 0 end)) as [Skuteczność z wycofaniami]
,(sum(CDV.PaymentValue))/(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)) as [Skutecznośc bez wycofań]
from
CaseDetailsView as CDV
where (CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL) and (CDV.ClientProductId in (@ProductId) or @ProductId IS NULL)
group by CDV.ClientNameShort, convert(date,CDV.DateImported),convert(date,CDV.EndServiceDate), CDV.ClientProductId, CDV.ProductName
```

I need a way to get rid of

```
group by ... CDV.ClientProductId, CDV.ProductName
```

Since I need few products to be shown as one result for exmaple:

```
CDV.ClientProductId in (1008,1007,1050)
```

This group by completly ruins results.

[image]

2 rows marked with black lines should be shown as one since they are in the same category however they have different ClientProductId :(

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont need to use group by just comment out this lines\

```
,count(CDV.CaseDetailsId) as [Ilość zleceń]
,convert(date,CDV.DateImported) as [Początek obsługi]
,convert(date,CDV.EndServiceDate) as [Koniec obsługi]
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital) as [Kapitał przekazany]
,sum(CDV.PaymentValue) as [Suma wpłat]
,sum(case when CDV.CaseStatus = 'Wycofana' then CDV.CurrentCapital else 0 end) as [Wartość wycofań]
,(sum(CDV.PaymentValue))/(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital) - sum(case when CDV.CaseStatus = 'Wycofana' then CDV.CurrentCapital else 0 end)) as [Skuteczność z wycofaniami]
,(sum(CDV.PaymentValue))/(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)) as [Skutecznośc bez wycofań]
..
group by CDV.ClientNameShort, convert(date,CDV.DateImported),convert(date,CDV.EndServiceDate), CDV.ClientProductId, CDV.ProductName
```

In addition, you shouldn't use these bunch of WHEN and CASE clauses in the SELECT part. It affects query efficiency badly. Best option is to do postprocessing by your server-side language.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer, since I don't see any difference between my query and yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Change group by to this:

```
GROUP BY 
  CDV.ClientNameShort, 
  convert(date,CDV.DateImported),
  convert(date,CDV.EndServiceDate), 
  CASE WHEN CDV.ClientProductId in (1008,1007,1050) THEN 1008 
       ELSE CDV.ClientProductId END,
  CDV.ProductName
```

Comment: I think we don't really understand each other.. Those results are shown right now: http://oi43.tinypic.com/2l8gh9f.jpg. Expected result would be 3 rows with 3+4 grouped as one since they have same "Kategoria sprawy"